# Nodemailer does not Send Mail Text

Tags: javascript, nodemailer

I can send my mail. But I can not send mail text. Where is problem, I do not know. if I write it like this `"mail text ........"`, it is running. but if I write as variable, mail text does not send.

```
function sendAlarmMail(emails, alarmMessage) {
    let mailAddresses = emails;
    let mailText = alarmMessage;
    try {
        let testAccount = nodemailer.createTestAccount();

    let transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
        maxConnections: 3,
        pool: true,
        host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
        port: 587,
        secure: false,
        auth: {
            user: 'xxxx@gmail.com',
            pass: 'xxxx'
        }
    });
    
    let message = {
        from: 'xxx@gmail.com',
        to: "xxxx@xxxxx.com",
        subject: 'Yüksek Enerji Kullanım Uyarısı',
        text: `${mailText}`
    }
    transport.sendMail(message, function (err, info) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            console.log("Mail Gönderilemedi !");
        } else {
            console.log(info);
            console.log("Mail Gönderildi !");
        }
    });
}

sendAlarmMail("mail1, mail2, mail3", "mail texts");
```

How can I send my text  in my mail. help please.

Comment: `text: \`${mailText}\`` can be written as `text: mailText` instead. How do you call `sendAlarmMail`?

Comment: I tried like that `text: mailText`. but it still does not send text of variable. I sure there is data in `mailText`. I wrote the function so `sendAlarmMail` in below of code. @ChrisG

Comment: I tried your code and it works for me as-is. Try adding `html: "<p>Mail Test</p>"` or something like that, but in my Thunderbird, I see `mail texts` as expected.

Comment: Why don't you use "alarmMessage" directly?

Comment: @akif there are a lot of code. I try to do dynamic my code.

Comment: @ChrisG it is like a joke. I do not understand why does not run properly.

Comment: (To be clear, your mail gets sent but it's empty, right?) Where are you sending the mail to? Are you looking at it in a program? Are you positive it is empty? Did you look at its source code? Did you try supplying an html part? Double-check that you aren't running an old version of your code (change the subject line and re-send).

Comment: I checked my nodemailer version. But there is no problem. I partially solved my problem. When I use html in maile content, mail text can not send together html. but I jus try to send mail text as a variable, mail text has been sended. But when I try to send the variable with html, it is running properly. but When I try to send `text: variable` and `html: <p>variable</p>`, just sending html. I do not understand. My problem has been solved. Thanks your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem had been solved When I remove `text:`. I wrote my variable into `html` code instead `text:`.

```
let message = {
            from: 'xxxx@gmail.com',
            to: emails,
            subject: 'Yüksek Enerji Kullanım Uyarısı',
            html: "<div><p>" + alarmMessage + "</p></div>"
}
```